# Safari local fonts do not load on first visit with Nuxt 2.15.3, Tailwind and Pwa Module

Tags: javascript, css, safari, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've created a nuxt pwa app, [www.shirime.one](https://shirime.one), it's working well,
but I have an issue with Safari mobile, custom fonts are not loaded.

When PWA is installed with safari on IOS, if I connect the device to my macbook I dont see the fonts folder,. If I refresh the PWA from safari inspector It's work. It's seems Nuxt PWA module can't load fonts folder when the PWA is installed with safari on IOS. I dont know why.

My nuxt pwa config:

```
pwa: {
    icon: {
      fileName: 'app-icon.png',
    },

    meta: {
      name: 'Shirime Challenge',
      mobileApp: true,
      mobileAppIOS: true,
      description: false,
      lang: false,
      theme_color: '#000000',
      ogHost: 'https://shirime.one',
      twitterCard: 'summary',
      twitterSite: '@jbty_dev',
      twitterCreator: '@jbty_dev',
    },
  },
```

My font faces:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nouveau';
  src: url('~/assets/fonts/NouveauRegular.eot');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nouveau';
  src: local('Nouveau Regular'), local('NouveauRegular'),
  url('~/assets/fonts/NouveauRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('~/assets/fonts/NouveauRegular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('~/assets/fonts/NouveauRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('~/assets/fonts/NouveauRegular.svg#NouveauRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
```

My tailwind config:

```
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin'

module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.{vue,js}',
    './layouts/**/*.vue',
    './pages/**/*.vue',
    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        heading: ['Nouveau', 'sans-serif'],
        body: ['Futura CondensedLight', 'sans-serif'],
        incantation: ['Stranger back in the Night', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      colors: {
        red: '#FF0000',
        redAccent: '#ff1414',
        red40: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)',
        black: '#000000',
        black92: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.92)',
        white: '#ffffff',
        white40: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
      },
      fontSize: {
        xs: '.82rem',
        sm: '.95rem',
        tiny: '.875rem',
        base: '1rem',
        lg: '1.125rem',
        xl: '1.25rem',
        '2xl': '1.5rem',
        '3xl': '2.2rem',
        '4xl': '2.9rem',
        '5xl': '3.3rem',
        '6xl': '3.8rem',
        '7xl': '6rem',
        '8xl': '11rem',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        '.no-text-shadow': {
          textShadow: 'none',
        },
        '.red-text-shadow': {
          textShadow: '0px 0px 10px rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
        },
        '.red-text-shadow-big': {
          textShadow: '0px 0px 15px rgba(255,0,0,0.6)',
        },
        '.white-text-shadow': {
          textShadow: '0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
        },
        '.red-box-b-shadow': {
          boxShadow: '0 18px 10px -10px  rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
        },
        '.white-box-b-shadow': {
          boxShadow: '0 18px 10px -10px  rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
        },

        '.backdrop-blur': {
          backdropFilter: 'blur(2px)',
        },
      }

      addUtilities(newUtilities)
    }),
  ],
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "shirime",
  "author": {
    "name": "Thery Jean-Baptiste",
    "email": "jb.thery@flameapp.fr",
    "url": "https://flameapp.fr"
  },
  "description": "Shirime Challenge - www.shirime.one digital ouija, make your friends believe that you speak with an all-knowing mind! Progressive Web App available for installation on Ios, Android, Windows, Mac Os and Linux.",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "lintfix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint **/*.{vue,css} --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:style",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": "eslint",
    "*.{css,vue}": "stylelint"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/amp": "^0.5.4",
    "@nuxtjs/google-adsense": "^1.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.21.1",
    "nuxt-lazy-load": "^1.2.5",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^12.0.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.0.1",
    "@nuxt/types": "~2.15.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.12.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a plugin that reload the page when new pwa version is released

Plugins folder

```
export default async () => {
  const workbox = await window.$workbox

  if (!workbox) {
    console.debug("Workbox couldn't be loaded.")
    return
  }

  workbox.addEventListener('installed', (event) => {
    if (!event.isUpdate) {
      console.debug('The PWA is on the latest version.')
      return
    }

    console.debug('There is an update for the PWA, reloading...')
    window.location.reload()
  })
}
```

Nuxt config

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/pwa-update.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

Have a nice day